# What does shift and multiply-accumulate mean in terms of Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: convolution

While reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08383.pdf), I came across the following paragraph -

"Our intuition is: the convolution operation consists of shift and multiply-accumulate.
We shift in the time dimension by ±1 and fold the multiply-accumulate from time dimension to channel dimension."

Can someone please explain what these terms mean?

Comment: It's an odd (to me) restatement of what convolution does.  Do you know what the convolution operator does?  Do you know what a multiply-accumulate operation is?

Comment: Also "intuition" isn't a great fit for a scientific paper.

Comment: See [the definition of Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition)